# Column widget draws a line between children when they are wrapped in specific widget with decoration. How can i cure this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The problem is visible on the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of what is happening]

Code of a main widget:

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: Decor(
        child: Container(),
      ),
      flex: 1,
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Decor(
        child: Container(),
      ),
      flex: 6,
    )
  ],
);
```

Code of a Decor widget:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: COLOR,
  ),
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: MEDIUM_PADDING,
  ),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(MEDIUM_PADDING),
  width: 300.0,
  child: child,
);
```

Answering in advance "Why would you even need to do such a Decor Widget"? Both flexibles will be populated with data of some sort. Second flexible will be with a ListView inside and the first one will be a "Header" for what is inside a ListView. Data is retrieved from server every 10s, so the main widget is wrapped with a StreamBuilder.

Problem is that StreamBuilder cannot be shrinked to the size of its child, whereas ListView can, so I wrap both "Header" and a ListView in Decor so that grey background color doesn't take all available space on a screen which than produces black line seen on a screenshot?

So the question is: is there a way either to remove the black line between two widgets in a column?

Also, if you know magic of how to shrink StreamBuilder to the size of its child please answer here too.

Comment: I think this line `padding: const EdgeInsets.all(MEDIUM_PADDING),` is causing the problem. Try making the padding horizontal only or removing it.

Comment: Also I tried doing the same thing in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b) but its showing no line,

Comment: Tried removing padding, margin and both, yet none of these changes made line disappear on real device. @Ryosuke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I know that this is not a very nice solution and more like workaround but I think the only way to get rid of the line is to set border color of the container in your Decor widget

```
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
   color: COLOR,
   border: Border.all(width: 0, color: COLOR) //added line
  ),
 margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
  horizontal: MEDIUM_PADDING,
  ),
 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(MEDIUM_PADDING),
 width: 300.0,
 child: child,
);
```

First I thought setting border width to 0 will help it but that didn't work.. Color did